# How to convert simple date from textbox to datetime in mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a date in textBox like 2014-17-04 i.e.(YYYY-DD-MM) I wnt to put it in the database such as 2014-04-17 00:00:00 ,So How can I do this. I have tried like following..

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO Date_Master(BirthDate) VALUES('"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtBirthdate.Text)+"')";
```

but it gives error that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" . So how can I insert values in the database using MySQL DATE_FORMAT?

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime TryParse or TryParseExact to test your input

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtBirthdate.Text, "yyyy-dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
{
     var insert = "INSERT INTO Date_Master(BirthDate) VALUES(@birthdate)";
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, yourConnection))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;     
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate",dt);

         cmd.Connection.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                  
      }
 }
```

`yyyy-dd-MM` matches your expected input.  And as @JonSkeet added, always use parameterized queries to avoid injection

Comment: ... and then use parameterized SQL for the database interaction.